# Which of these sentences is correct? (“as much as” application)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I always have problem by using "as much as". Assume I start job 1 at 9 AM, and job 2 at 10 Am.

Which of these sentences can be correct?

1- I postpone job 2 **as much as** an hour... .

2- I postpone job 2 **by as much as** an hour... .

3- I postpone job 2 **by** an hour... .

Indeed, I want to highlight the value "an hour" in my sentence.

Comment: "As much as" means *up to* an hour, and so, critically also implies it could be less than an hour (in fact, it treats the full hour as the most extreme, and therefore, least likely, case); by contrast, *by* means precisely an hour.

Answer (score 0):

*'I will postpone the second job for an hour'* means for exactly 1 hour.

*'I will postpone the job for as much as an hour'* means up to 60 minutes.

The correct way to use 'by' is to say, *'I will postpone the time when I start the second job by an hour.'*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with #3 "I will postpone job 2 by an hour"; however it works just as well without "by ".  "I will postpone job 2 an hour.